# How do I modify an Expandable String Value in the registry with PowerShell or a batch file?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, windows-registry, file-association

I would like to use a PowerShell or batch script to modify an existing expandable string value to another.  Specifically, I want to change the default value at

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\edit\command

to

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5\Photoshop.exe" "%1"
```

I can do this directly in the registry editor, but when I export it as a .reg file, I get a bunch of hex nonsense; obviously that's not very intuitive:

[image]

So if I were to use an alternative method instead, such as PowerShell or a batch script, I would hope that I could actually read the path in plain text when viewing the code (since I can't inside the .reg file).

Can this be done with a PowerShell or batch script in a way that keeps the filepath readable?

Comment: Is that the hex values translated in your screen shot? This means in that hex content, there is a human readable file that and that is what you want to see?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, yes, for some reason whenever you export an Expandable String Value from the registry, the exported .reg file looks like that, even though the actual content I entered into the registry editor field editor was exactly the string above with the path to Photoshop.  Because it's so obscured, I hoped that using another method would make it easier to modify the path in the script file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done using PowerShell

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCR:\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\edit\command" -Name "(Default)" -PropertyType ExpandString -Value '"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5\Photoshop.exe" "%1"'
```

[Read about it here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-itemproperty?view=powershell-6)